# Filter a column using IF statement in powerquery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm having trouble filtering my columns in powerquery. I'm using a parameter to filter my 'Island' NI or SI, however I am struggling to find a way to keep all the data when no parameter is inputted.

I would like to leave the column full (NI and SI) if no input is provided. I've added two pictures on imgur below. I'm fairly new here.

I've tried using an if statement but couldn't figure out the right piece of code or if it's even possible to do so.

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6td5P.png). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY1ii.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. What is the value of `IslandChoice` when you have no selection? An empty string? `""`

Answer (score 0):

Note: **see the very end for a version that does not need to hard-code values**.

First let's test if the search filter is a valid value. If not, don't filter anything.

```
if IslandChoice is "NI" or "SI"
    then filter using IslandChoice
else
    show everything
```

The other route is

```
if IslandChoice is not "NI" and is not "SI"
    show everything
else
    filter using IslandChoice
```

It depends if you want invalid values to show nothing, or everything.

First check "is this filter a valid choice?

```
[Island] = "SI" or [Island] = "WI"
```

If either one is true, then it's good. If both are false, then it's an invalid key.

```
filter_if_valid = Table.SelectRows(
    Source,
    (row) =>
        if IslandChoice = "SI" or IslandChoice = "NI" then 
            row[Island] = IslandChoice            
        else
            true
)
```

## How does it work, and where is `each` ?

`each` is a normal function. It's `sugar`, a shortcut that declares a function which has a single arugment. (If you need more, use a function declaration)

see more: [Details on the grammar of `each` is in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-functions#simplified-declarations)

### `each` implicitly creates the variable named `_`

Because `each` abstracts a couple of things, it's harder to tell what's happening.

1. `each` creates a variable named `_` which references the current row.
2. `each` declares a function without the arguments part

Functions follow the form

```
(arguments) => return_expression
```

Written using `each` it removes the `(arguments) =>` portion.

```
each return_expression
```

`return_expression` can be a simple `[Column] = 10` test. (Or it can create many local variables using a `let` .. `in` expression inside the function).

These statements are all **exactly equivelent** functions

```
each [Island] = IslandChoice

each _[Island] = IslandChoice

(_) => _[Island] = IslandChoice

(row) => row[Island] = IslandChoice
```

They all

- declare a `function` without a name
- accept exactly 1 argument
- read the column `[Island]` in the current table row
- returns `true` if they are equal, else `false`

## original filter

after replacing `each` you had:

```
always_filter_table = Table.SelectRows(
    Source, 
    (row) =>
        row[Island] = IslandChoice
),
```

## new filter

```
filter_if_valid = Table.SelectRows(
    Source,
    (row) =>
        if IslandChoice = "SI" or IslandChoice = "NI" then 
            row[Island] = IslandChoice            
        else
            true
)
```

## filter without hard-coding values

This will run alone without any requirements. Create a new -> `blank query`

```
let
    Source = #table(
        {"Island", "Point Of Connection"},
        {
            {"SI", "STK0331"},
            {"SI", "TIM0111"},
            {"NI", "ZEJ2395"},
            {"NI", "XER9345"},
            {"WI", "QXF9785"}
        }
    ),

    is_valid_filter = (value as any, valid_values as list) => 
        List.Contains( valid_values, value ),

    // use one or the other if you want all existing values to be valid
    static_valid_filters = {"SI", "NI"},
    dynamic_valid_filters = List.Distinct(
        Source[Island]
    ),

    IslandChoice = "NI",

    // if filter is a valid value, filter using it. 
    // otherwise show all.
    filtered_when_valid = Table.SelectRows(
        Source,
        (row) =>
            if is_valid_filter(
                IslandChoice, static_valid_filters
            ) then
                row[Island] = IslandChoice            
            else
                true
    )
in
    filtered_when_valid
```